Azure Devops Pipeline conditional
I am struggling to get conditions based on chosen variables correct. My pipeline:
parameters:
- name: versionTag
  displayName: After the tagging, should we do a patch, minor or major version update?
  type: string
  default: patch
  values:
  - patch
  - minor
  - major

- script: echo you want to do a patch version bump
  condition: eq(variables.versionTag, 'patch')

- script: echo you want to do a minor version bump
  condition: eq(variables.versionTag, 'minor')

When I run the pipeline it just says: "Skipping step due to condition evaluation" even though I choose "patch" when I start the pipeline.
I have also tried:
- ${{ if eq(variables['versionTag'], 'patch') }}:
  - script: echo "you want to do a patch version bump"
- ${{ if eq(variables['versionTag'], 'minor') }}:
  - script: echo "you want to do a minor version bump"

It gives the same output.
Any advice?

You're using parameters but in the conditions or {{ if }} statements you're referencing variables.
You should use template expression syntax to reference the parameters - in this case, ${{ parameters.versionTag }}.
Using conditions:
steps:
  - script: echo you want to do a patch version bump
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.versionTag }}', 'patch')
    displayName: 'Patch version bump'

  - script: echo you want to do a minor version bump
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.versionTag }}', 'minor')
    displayName: 'Minor version bump'

Using {{ if }} statements:
steps:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.versionTag, 'patch') }}:
    - script: echo you want to do a patch version bump
      displayName: 'Patch version bump'

  - ${{ if eq(parameters.versionTag, 'minor') }}:
    - script: echo you want to do a minor version bump
      displayName: 'Minor version bump'


Working, thanks so much. I also had to go double check my understanding of parameters vs variables!
